# Why DISTINCT keyword is decreasing my search time and increasing performace in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I am new to SQL and SQL Server and I am using SQL server 2012.

but recently I encountered a weird thing while working with SQL server. I got that adding DISTINCT in my query actually decreases my search time of query and returns result early as of not using DISTINCT in query.

I have a table with nearly 96 columns and I want to search all columns for a search string. I want to get the record if a search string exists anywhere in the table. For that I am using query like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5000 [Row Id] ,[Account],[Created Date],[First Name],[A].[City] ... rest column
FROM [dbo].[Account] 
WHERE ([Row Id] LIKE '%{search_string}%' OR [Account] LIKE '%{search_string}%' ... rest columns})
```

I know that this is not most effictive way but still it worked for me.
I used DISTINCT as some rows are duplicates in table. and table contains nearly 1 million records.

But later my manager asked to decrease search time of query so I changed query and suddenly my search time increased by nearly 4x than previous.
I inspected and got that I had removed DISTINCT to optimize query. But that made it slower.
By slower I mean it's 4x slower than previous query.

I am confused that how can just adding or removing DISTINCT keyword can make so much difference.
and removing DISTINCT should optimize my query but it's degrading it.

Note: I have experimented with query and it's really with just DISTINCT and not any other factor.

and even one thing to add while experiminting with query I redued the number of columns to search to cehek if searching more columns are creating problems. and I just search 5 columns now like

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5000 [Row Id] ,[Account],[Created Date],[First Name],[A].[City]
FROM [dbo].[Account] 
WHERE ([Row Id] LIKE '%{search_string}%' OR [Account] LIKE '%{search_string}%' ... 3 more columns})
```

but doing so still gives the same result. But here if I remove the TOP 5000 it again increases my search time even though query returns no(0) records.

If i run below query

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Row Id] ,[Account],[Created Date],[First Name],[A].[City]
FROM [dbo].[Account] 
WHERE ([Row Id] LIKE '%{search_string}%' OR [Account] LIKE '%{search_string}%' ... 3 more columns})
```

it nearly 3x takes more time to serach. See only TOP is removed from above query.

Now I know that adding a TOP LIMIT is good. But here we are not getting any results so how can adding TOP LIMIT can decrease time.

Note: Table has no primary key or index columns.

Really confused with what is happening can any body help me with this,
below is my SQL server info

product: Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise (64-bit)

OS: Microsoft Windows NT 6.2 (9200)

platform: NT x64

version: 11.0.2100.60

Memory: 65491 MB

processors: 8

Server Collation: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Is Clustered: False

Is HADR Enabled: False

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: *"I am new to SQL and SQL Server and I am using SQL server 2012."* If you are new, JI suggest a more recent version of SQL Server; 2012 has 2 months, to the day, of extended support left and then it is *completely* unsupported.

Comment: *"Now I know that adding a TOP LIMIT is good."* Wrong; your query has no `ORDER BY` so the `TOP` is *bad*. A `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` is a sure sign of a flaw. This means that the data engine is free to return what ever arbitrary row(s) it wants, and the row(s) could be different every time you run said query. If you are using `TOP` you need to ensure the query has an `ORDER BY` so that you get consistent and reliable results.

Comment: You have multiple `LIKE` and `OR` clauses there; if your `LIKE` expressions have leading wildcards, then that's going to make the query non-SARGable, and those `OR`s could result in a difficult query to optimise anyway. In truth, we don't have enough information here; especially as much of the query is omitted and we don't know what search values you are using.

Comment: We would need to see the query plans for the different versions of your query to tell you why this is happening.

Comment: There are about 1 million rows in the table. The conditions can match any number of rows from zero to one million. The DBMS is completely oblivious to how many rows to expect. Depending on what it happens to expect and how it deals with your offer to stop at 5000 arbitrary matches, it will decide for the execution plan it considers best. Whatever this decision, I agree with you that the `DISTINCT` in the query should in no way make the query faster. This would indicate a flaw in the DBMS optimizer.

Comment: When checking the query speed, keep in mind that data (the query's execution plan, data in the database, data on the hard disk) can be cached, so run the queries multiple times in order to be sure that one version really is *always* faster than the other.

Comment: In addition to other comments, I suspect removing `DISTINCT` was not _the only change_, and even if it was, it's possible that the original plan was constructed based on certain statistics and/or parameter values, and the removal of `DISTINCT` - since it is new query text - forced a new plan to be generated, and that plan was made based on _different_ statistics and/or parameter values. But with the info we have, all we can do is guess. Post the different query plans somewhere and that will give us more than guesswork.

Comment: There is no way we can answer this without query plans. Please share them via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: Hi @Charlieface have got query execution plans for both versions of my query.
previous: [link](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1bFV9jUq)

Later: [link](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyV7FKiU9)

I have only changed distinct in both of my queries

can you please explain me what HASH match and Parallelism do change when I add DISTINCT to in my query. and why they occur whey I add DISTINCT

Answer (score 0):

The logical order of operations in SQL puts `TOP` and `OFFSET` *after* `DISTINCT`. And `DISTINCT` functions like `GROUP BY` so it has to group all those columns. This is why you get a `Hash Aggregate`.

So when you add `DISTINCT` in a query with `TOP`

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100)
  a, b
FROM table
```

this is like doing the following

```sql
SELECT TOP (100)
  *
FROM (
  SELECT
    a, b
  FROM table
  GROUP BY a, b
) t
```

so the whole table has to be scanned first.

---

Presumably, what you *actually* intended was for the grouping to occur *after* selecting the top 100 rows. This means that you can do a quick scan of the table for the first 100 rows, then group only those. You can do this like this

```sql
SELECT
  a, b
FROM (
  SELECT TOP (100)
    a, b
  FROM table
) t
GROUP BY a, b
```

> This is one reason why `DISTINCT` should generally be avoided, it is a highly confusing operator.

Another thing to think about: **Why does this need `DISTINCT` at all?** Why do you not have a primary key on this table? If you did then the `DISTINCT` would be redundant as every row would be unique anyway.

> One further point to make: Don't use column names that require quoting with `[]`, it's really annoying.